# My own proof of "Every neighborhood is open" (Rudin's definition)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Previously, someone posted his/her proof of "every neighborhood is open" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838349/correctness-of-proof-that-every-neighborhood-is-an-open-set). I am focusing on the same statement, but it seems that my approach is different from his/hers. Could someone comment on my own proof? Here we go:

Let $X$ be a metric space and $p\in X$. Fix $r>0$. Define a neighborhood around $p$ as $N_r (p)=\{q\in X| d(p, q)<r\}$. Now, take $w = \frac{r}{2}$. Then, $N_w (p)\subset N_r(p)$. In other words, every point of $N_r(p)$ is interior. Therefore, $N_r (p)$ is open. Since $r$ is arbitrary, this proves every neighborhood is open.

**Update:**

Under my definition of "neighborhood," can I prove in this way instead: For all $m\in N_r(p)$, take $w=\frac{r−d(m,p)}{2}$. Then, $N_w(m)\subset N_r(p)$.

**Update2**

From the hints given in comments, I solve it:

Assume $m\in N_r(p)$ and $q\in N_w(m)$. Take $w=r-d(m, p)$. Then, $d(p, q)\leq d(p, m) + d(m, q)< d(p, m) + r-d(m,p) =r$.

Thanks to @JoséCarlosSantos and @fleablood !

Comment: " In other words, every point of Nr(p) is interior. "  You only proved it for $p$.  There are other points in $N_r(p)$ than $p$.

Comment: Well, you have to *prove* $N_w(m) \subset N_r(p)$.  It's not immediately clear as a given.

Comment: But yes, you can prove thatn $N_w(m) \subset N_r(p)$ by cosidering that if $q \in N_w(m)$ then $d(p,q) < r$.  (Use triagle inequality.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, you can call that a neighbourhood, if you wish, but that's **not** the standard definition of neighbourhood. So, the only thing that you might have proved was that those sets to which **you** call neighbourhoods are open sets.

In the second place, your proof is wrong. All that it proves is that there is an open ball centered at *p* contained in your set. It does **not** prove that for **every** point of $N_r(p)$ there is such a ball.

Comment: Thanks! Under my definition of "neighborhood," can I prove in this way instead: For all $m\in N_r (p)$, take $w= \frac{r-d(m,p)}{2}$. Then, $N_w(m)\subset N_r(p)$.

Comment: I think it is the standard definition of a neighborhood.  The problem is the OP only proved that $p$  is an interior point.  Not that every point is.

Comment: "can I prove in this way instead:?"  Well, try it.  Can you prove that?  Hint: use the triangle inequality prove if $q \in N_w(m)$ then $d(q,p) < r$

Comment: @fleablood The standard definition of neighborhood in a metric space is: $N$ is a neighborhood if $N$ **contains** an open ball centered at $p$.

Comment: @JamesWang You can even take $w=r-d(m,p).$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos As we are using "Rudin's Definition" a neighborhood *is* the ball. (Principals of Mathematical Analysis: Def 2.18 a.)  Anyway, I hope you agree the point is moot.  That's not the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't say "define a neighborhood".

That sounds as though you are defining the term to be something different than it is.  Rudin uses this "open ball" definition of "neighborhood" so, although, other comments and answers object, it is okay to *DECLARE* $N_r(p)$ to be a neighborhood.

Now you have shown that if $N_{\frac r2}(p)\subset N_r(p)$ so $p$ is an interior point.

Then you say "In other words, every point of Nr(p) is interior."

Um, say what?  Since when has $p$ been every point? $N_r(p)$ contains points that are not $p$.  You must prove *these* points are also interior points.

The only real way that I can see is to chose an $s$ so that $N_s(q) \subset N_r(p)$.  (Note: $N_s(q)$ and $N_r(p)$ have different centers.).  And if you know that $d(p,q) < r$ then there *is* an $s$ that ca be chosen so that $N_s(q) \subset N_r(p)$.  Do you see how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I use triangle inequality and get it: $d(p, q)\leq d(p, m) + d(m, q)\leq d(p, m) + \frac{r-d(m,p)}{2} = \frac{r +d(m,p)}{2}<\frac{r+r}{2}=r$. The "<" comes from the definition of $m$ being a point in $N_r(p)$.

Comment: Presuming $m \in N_r(p)$ and $q \in N_w(m)$ that is correct.