# Every neighborhood is an open set proof question

Tags: real-analysis

> Theorem: Every neighborhood is an open set.

Proof: Consider a neighborhood $E=N_r(p)$, and let $q$ be any point of $E$. $$\text{There is a positive real number $h$ such that $d(p,q)=r-h$} \tag 1$$
$$\text{For all points s such that $d(q,s) \lt h$, we have $d(p,s) \leq d(p,q)+d(q,s) \lt r-h+h=r$, so that $s \in E$.} \tag 2 $$ Thus $q$ is an interior point of $E$.

Definition: A neighborhood of $p$ is a set $N_r(p)$ consisting of all q such that $d(p,q) \lt r$, for some $r \gt 0$. The number $r$ is called the radius of $N_r(p)$.

I know from definition, to prove a set $E$ is open, we need to show every point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$. I still don't get those tagged equations as to why.

Comment: $[-1,1]$ is a neighborhood of $0$ and is not open. What is your definition of neighborhood?

Comment: @JensRenders: Judging from the question, the OP is actually talking about open balls in a metric space. By the way, there are topologists for whom *neighborhood* is synonymous with *open set*; see, for instance, Ryszard Engelking’s well-known text *General Topology*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's why I ask. This should be included in the question.

Comment: Definition of neighborhood of a point (Bourbaki?) is a set containing an open set containing the point.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Well that's not the definition being used here as per my example. OP is also not treating neighborhood as synonymous with open set as in *General Topology* which BrianM.Scott mentions, because that makes the question trivial.

Comment: What is your definition of neighborhood?  It seems to differ from both Bourbaki and General Topology.

Comment: I think OP uses open balls as neighborhoods as @BrianM.Scott suggests, and then this question is almost identical to [“Every neighborhood is open” (Rudin's definition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828815/my-own-proof-of-every-neighborhood-is-open-rudins-definition?rq=1). Notice how this question is posed better as it includes the definition they use.

Comment: @herbsteinberg sorry about the confusion, I added it.

Comment: In general, the definition of an open set does not require the space to have a metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your definition of "neighborhood" is a ball of the form $N_r(p)=\{ x \mid d(x, p) \lt r \}$ and that your definition of an "open set" is a set that has the property that every point of the set has a ball around it that's completely contained in the set.

Then seeing that balls are in fact open sets is just using the triangle inequality.  Any point $x$ in a ball around $p$ must be some positive (i.e., non-zero) distance $\varepsilon$ from the boundary of the ball.  That's because we use strict inequality to define the ball -- our proof would fail if we used the alternative definition $\overline{N_r(p)}= \{x \mid d(x, p) \leq r \}$ because some points of this "closed ball" lie exactly on the boundary, not some positive distance away from it.

So now think about a ball of radius $\frac \varepsilon 2$ around $x$.  The triangle inequality tells us that entire ball around $x$ must be contained in the ball around $p$.  Since $x$ was an arbitrary point in the ball around $p$, we've proved that any point in the ball around $p$ is in fact in its interior, so the ball is open and we have justified our use of the term "open ball" for a ball of this form.